# Move common gradle code into separate file works with groovy, kotlin gives "Unresolved reference"

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a multi module project with several Android library modules. I pulled the common android gradle configurations into a separate file and apply it in each module.

gradle/androidDefaults.gradle.kts

```
android {
    compileSdk = 33
    ...
}
```

Each android library modules includes it like this:

```
apply {
    from("${project.rootDir}/gradle/androidDefaults.gradle.kts")
}
```

This works fine as long as `androidDefaults` is a Groovy file, but when I try to convert it to Kotlin, then i get an `Unresolved reference` error

```
e: myProjectDir/gradle/androidDefaults.gradle.kts:2:1: Unresolved reference: android
```

I understand that, since it is a separate file, I need to somehow tell it what `android` is, but I am not quite sure how. I've tried to add the android or the kotlin DSL plugin in there, but that did not work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-07-14 12:48:15 UTC
Revision:     c7db7b958189ad2b0c1472b6fe663e6d654a5103

Kotlin:       1.6.21
Groovy:       3.0.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          11.0.16 (BellSoft 11.0.16+8-LTS)
OS:           Mac OS X 13.0 aarch64
```